# What mushroom is this?

Tags: species-identification, mycology

A lot of these popped up recently in our backyard (St. Louis, Missouri, United States).  They are all grouped into these clusters and there were probably 5 of these big clusters.

Anyone know what type of mushrooms they are?  [image]

Comment: Where do you live?

Comment: @Remi.b I live in St. Louis, Missouri, United States.

Comment: http://www.mycokey.com/newMycoKeySite/MycoKeyIdentQuick.html found a page might help.

Comment: Pick up one; and add a photograph of what are beneath the cap. especially if there is any annulus and volva around the stipe. add 1 photograph of close-up of gill-patterns.